# Compaq RAM that does not fit into Dell laptops

Tags: laptop, memory

So I pulled out this weirdo SODIMM RAM stick from a Compaq laptop, and much to my suprise it's slit is at a little different point, and so it does not fit into our other Dell laptops.

Is it a different type? What's going on here?

[image]

And if you want a close-up look at the 2 RAM sticks:

[image]

Comment: Can you post the model numbers of each laptop?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From a quick peek at [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SO-DIMM), i'd guess the regular ram is DDR 2 and the other is DDR1 - it seems to match up with the big SVG (linked below) on the page

Incredibly useful diagram showing pinouts

[image]

[SVG version here if you need it bigger](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/95/Laptop_SODIMM_DDR_Memory_Comparison_V2.svg)  showing the pin positions for being sure. - its an SVG so i can't link it directly. Also, the notch on the ram is always on the same side - count the number of pins to be sure.

The systems are probably from different generations and just happen to use utterly incompatable forms of standard ram. It would be easy to check from an OS - using LSHW in linux or WMIC or a front end to that in windows